# How can a character pointer be assigned to a character variable?

Tags: c

Phew! I have the following code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char t[10] = "John";
    char x = t;
    printf("%c\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

How can the compiler not give me an error here? Also, the printf statement is outputting different results. What exactly is getting assigned to the variable x?

Comment: been a while since I dealt with C, but x is probably one byte of the pointer `t`. if you print out `t`, you'll find that `x` corresponds to it somehow.

Comment: @MarcB That is correct. `x` will end up with the low-order bits of the address of `t`.

Comment: It should produce a warning with almost any compiler at the default warning level, but it does not produce an error because it is not an error. Bad code, yes, but not incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with warnings you'll get the following complaint:

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

The reason it doesn't fail compilation is because three things happen under the hood:

- first the array decays to a pointer (arrays and pointers are *not* the same, but arrays 'decay' to pointers when necessary),
- then that pointer is converted to an integer,
- finally the integer is converted to a `char` and assigned to `x`.

The conversion from integer to character is not a problem (and it happens all the time since character-constants in C are actually `int`s), but converting a pointer to an integer is rarely ever the programmer's intention, hence the warning. It isn't strictly wrong but not very meaningful either.

So in the end `printf` prints whatever is left of the address of the first element of `t`.

Answer (score 2):

In c, a pointer is a scalar value, so is a char, and so is an int.  Scalar basically means that it's a number.  All scalars can be added, multiplied, etc.  There's always a way to convert from one scalar to another.

When you do
    `char x = t;`
It implicitly casts the pointer `t` to a char.  The variable `x` will contain the 8 least significant bits of the pointer.

Different compilers handle scalar conversions differently.  Sometimes they require you to explicitly cast one to another. e.g. `char x = (char)t;`  Some will give you warning if an implicit cast results in a loss of precision.  (A cast from int to char can lose precision, but a cast from char to int cannot lose precision)  Some compilers will give you an error whenever you try to implicitly cast anything.

Whether you get an error or a warning depends on your compiler and the compiler's settings.  Try enabling warnings.

In gcc you can enable all warnings by adding -Wall to the compile command, or you can turn all warnings into errors by adding -Werror

Comment: Thanks! Very nicely explained

Answer (score -1):

In C, the name of an array most of the time means a pointer to its first element. It is certainly valid to cast a pointer to an integer, and in C a `char` is just an integer, even if probably dodgy code. In any case, here gcc-4.8.2-7.fc19.x86_64 tells me:

```
$ gcc -c xxx.c 
xxx.c: In function ‘main’:
xxx.c:6:14: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 char x = t;
          ^
```

while clang-3.3-4.fc19.x86_64 goes:

```
$ clang -c xxx.c 
xxx.c:6:10: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing
      'char' with an expression of type 'char [10]' [-Wint-conversion]
    char x = t;
         ^   ~
1 warning generated.
```

No errors, but dire warnings.